# Users Bypassing Workbook Protections - What Did I overlook?

Tags: microsoft-excel, password-protection, users, dropdownlist, ignore

I created a Excel 2016 workbook that was to be sent to multiple department heads to then be distributed to their personnel to solicit input on a topic.

Some of the columns were free response; some were dropdowns using data validation approaches. The dropdown options were on a hidden tab and the workbook was protected so you couldn't unhide it.

The target worksheet with the various columns of kinds information itself was also locked; cell protection was enabled to allow only editing within the designated columns and I performed multiple tests/hand-jam exercises to try to "break" the rules and it seemed to work.

Of course, some users somehow found a way to return the workbook with values that were not allowed in the dropdown cells (i.e. their options were "Yes/No" and they put in "N/A" or even a paragraph of text) - and when I delete them and attempt to recreate it, the workbook dutifully prevents me from doing so.

As extremely annoying as this exercise was (seriously, when there are dropdowns who works this hard to break the rules and make your entire submission worthless/a huge hassle to the person who has to collect it??)... I view it also as a learning opportunity.

I've done some searches on this but it's a difficult topic to parse using obvious Google searches. I don't believe any of these individuals would have been able to use any sort of macro or VBA to "hack" the password protection.

So... **what are some ways to ignore/work around password protected dropdowns**? If you wanted to be annoying and supply info in a manner that is clearly out of format with what was intended and make my life hard, how would you do it?

I'm hoping to use this to grown my own Excel skills, and I appreciate any tips you might have.

Thank you.

Comment: Write now difficult to be judgmental since not aware that what has been applied to protect those DDs,,, if possible either share those rules or the WB on cloud to examine and test the NEW RULEs !

Comment: Hi and welcome to SU! Please edit your post and include a screenshot of the data validation dialog while you have selected the cell where the user has entered the paragraph of text in the yes/no cell. Take that screenshot from the returned workbook before doing anything to it and then take the same screenshot from exactly the same cell in the workbook before you sent it to the department head. Please add both to your post so we can see.

Comment: One way to circumvent the data validation is to use copy & paste (from an unprotected cell or from another workbook or generally from the clipboard). I do not know how to prevent this.